# Aspose.net pdf: Obtain number of table rows moved to next page

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.pdf

Is there a way to obtain number of table rows moved to next page on page break and then conditionally move the whole table to the next page if there is e.g less than 5 rows on next page? ProcessParagraphs() and Save() are updating the pages count but Paragraphs collection is empty after invoking those methods (Paragraphs are rendered and there is no way to get these paragraph objects again, I guess).

Comment: Please share a narrowed down code snippet and generated PDF document to elaborate your requirements, so that we may investigate the scenario to help you out. You can share requested data by uploading it to any file sharing server like Google Drive, Dropbox etc. **P.S:** I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8k2ht8QS <- here is the code. When I want to know how much table rows were moved to the next page, is summing heights of all items and modulo dividing the only way to know how many rows are on next page?

Comment: We are afraid that the shared code snippet can not be compiled because it includes some undefined methods and properties. Please share a narrowed down sample application reproducing this scenario. However, you can sum table.Top, page's Top margin and table.Height or row.Height property in order to check if the table fits on the page or if it will flow to the next page.